# How does this MATLAB code make an image into a binary image?

Tags: image, matlab

```
v = videoinput('winvideo', 1, 'YUY2_320x240');
s = serial('COM1', 'BaudRate', 9600);
fopen(s);
while(1)
h = getsnapshot(v);
rgb = ycbcr2rgb(h);
for i = 1:240
    for j = 1:320
         if rgb(i,j,1) > 140 && rgb(i,j,2) < 100    % use ur own conditions
            bm(i, j) = 1;
        else
            bm(i, j) = 0;
        end
    end
end
```

This is the code i got from my senior regarding image processing using MATLAB. The above code is to convert the image to binary image, But in the code `rgb(i, j, 1) > 140` I didn't understand that command. How to select that 140 and what does that `rgb(i, j, 1)` mean?

Answer (score 3):

You have an RGB image `rgb` where the third dimension are the RGB color planes.  Thus, `rgb(i,j,1)` is the red value at row `i`, column `j`.

By doing `rgb(i,j,1)>140` it tests if this red value is greater than 140.  The value 140 appears to be *ad hoc*, picked for a specific task.

The code is *extremely* inefficient as there is no need for a loop:

```
bm = rgb(:,:,1)>140 & rgb(:,:,2)<100;
```

Note the change from `&&` to the element-wise operator `&`. Here I'm assuming that the size of  `rgb` is 240x320x3.

---

Edit: The threshold values you choose completely depend on the task, but a common approach to automatic thresholding is is Otsu's method, [`graythresh`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/graythresh.html). You can apply it to a single color plane to get a threshold:

```
redThresh = graythresh(rgb(:,:,1)) * 255;
```

Note that `graythresh` returns a value on [0,1], so you have to scale that by the data range.

Comment: can u suggest me how can we get 140, 100 such values from an image using matlab?

Comment: @user3443200 See Edit, but I suggest `graythresh` as a starting point.